# Is it possible NOT to update url in Wordpress, when title is changed?

Tags: wordpress

Every time you change blog title in Wordpress, url is changed. Is there a setting, so url won't be changed.
Thanks!

Comment: it wont change the slug if you change the title after first publish

Comment: ok, so it only changes url every time when I'm in a draft mode?

Comment: if you publish once it wont change

Answer (score 1):

Everytime Blog url wont change, only for first publish it will take title content,

Next time if you are changing or updating the title it wont update the slug.